# Trying to implement Explainable AI on Neural Network (RNN/LSTM/GRU). Do I need Logistic Regression? And Which method should I apply? Lime or Shap?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, recurrent-neural-network, shap, lime

Trying to implement Explainable AI on Neural Network(RNN/LSTM/GRU).
Doi need Logistic Regression? And Which method should I apply? Lime or Shap ?